# In app settings (application is closed)

Tags: objective-c, inappsettingskit, inappsettings

My application crashes when I close the settings.
Even with a standard animation (`UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`) button "Done" is not working..
What could be wrong?

**-EDIT-** Apparently I was not quite accurate in describing the problem: XCode does not receive notice of a crash. The application simply closes. As a result, achievements gained during the session are lost.

```cpp
- (IBAction)BarButtonPageCurlAction:(id)sender {
IASKAppSettingsViewController *SettingsViewController;
SettingsViewController = [[[IASKAppSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IASKAppSettingsView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
SettingsViewController.delegate = self;
//SettingsViewController.showDoneButton = NO;
//SettingsViewController.showCreditsFooter = NO;
SettingsViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
UINavigationController *NavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:SettingsViewController] autorelease];
//[NavController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:NavController animated:YES];}
```

my class files:

- [.m](http://pastebin.com/zP6u0NS7)
- [.h](http://pastebin.com/TdVVpbhp)

Comment: Can you paste your exception here?

Comment: I do not quite understand you. I have not used exceptions. Attached the full class code

Comment: He means the stacktrace (with symbols) showing *where* it crashed.

Comment: ...or even the description of the error that caused the crash, which is usually an exception.  (If you don't see one, use the Breakpoint Navigator to set a break on Objective-C exceptions.)

Comment: Please paste you SettingsViewController code also.

Comment: Apparently I was not quite right describes the problem: xcode does not receive notice of crash. The application simply closes. As a result, lost achievements of the previous session with the application

Comment: Class of SettingsViewController: http://pastebin.com/yks6d9CX & http://pastebin.com/s55e5WZQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the proper delegate methods implemented. Look at the documentation of Inappsettings, there are methods used for dismissing the settings view.